# convert 3d cell array in 2d cell array

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, cell-array

I transformed a structure *S* (with 13 fields and 96 rows, some fields are made of numbers, others of strings) into a cell array:

```
myCell= struct2cell(S);
```

So, I obtained a 3d cell array *myCell* 13x1x96, and I would like to transform it in a 2d cell array 96x13. Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: something like `(squeeze(myCell)).'` perhaps? The `squeeze` removes the singleton dimension.

Comment: @Benoit_11, thanks for your answer. I tried, and now *myCell* is 13x96, so at least 2d cell array, which is very good :). How can I now swap the rows with the columns and viceversa, in order to have *myCell* as 96x13?

Comment: @dede Transpose the output: `result = myCell.'`

Comment: @mikkola, thanks :) It works perfectly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general solution than what was suggested would employ the [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) function:

> `B = permute(A,order)` rearranges the dimensions of `A` so that they are in the order specified by the vector `order`.
>
> ...
>
> `permute` and `ipermute` are a generalization of transpose (`.'`) for multidimensional arrays.

In your case, running the command `new_Cell = permute(myCell,[3,1,2])` would make the `13x1x96` `96x13`. As you can see, `permute` removes trailing singleton dimensions (resembling [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html)).

(Tested on MATLAB 2015b)